# Leave tmate after calling application closed

Tags: c++, linux, tmux

In my application ( c++, linux) in some cases I need to open tmate session and send session key to client( my app run in screenless RaPI and so user can't see keys).
Because I can't redirect tmate to file ( if I use something like ** **", tmate still write messages to stdio and file leaves empty), I do it by opening pipe and reading tmate output:

FILE pf = popen( "tmate -F &");

char data[512];

while( true)

{

if ( fgets( data, 512, pf) ==NULL)

```
 break;

    //parsing data, accepting keys
```

}

Problem is that if application exits, tmate session closed too. And I need it continue running after closing application

How can I disown process so it still run after application death?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. It looks strange, but if I call tmate without ampersand ( of course in different thread), session still works after calling application exits